# jquery pop up having to press twice"OK" twice in order to make it disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a problem where i am trying to find out why do i have to press the "ok" button of the pop up button twice in order to make it disappear. I can see from my code that i just have only one alert statement and still it behaves as if i may have accidently called two alert statements

```
function intialiseKendoGrid(date) {
     gridResult = $('#grid').kendoGrid({
         scrollable: {
             virtual: true
         },
         navigatable: true,
         groupable: true,
         sortable: true,
         selectable: "row",
         pageable: true,

         pageable: {
             input: true,
             numeric: false
         },

         resizable: true,
         reorderable: true,
         filterable: {
             extra: false
         },
         columns: [{
             field: "DealNumber",
             width: 150,
             title: "DealNumber",

             filterable: {
                 operators: {
                     string: {
                         startswith: "Starts With",
                         contains: "Contains"
                     }
                 }

             },
         },
         {
             field: "DealIssuer",
             width: 150,
             title: "Issuer",
             filterable: {
                 operators: {
                     string: {
                         startswith: "Starts With",
                         contains: "Contains"
                     }
                 }
             },
             //template: "<a href='http://manager.dealogic.com/ManagerV3/CPCortex/Default/${DealNumber}'>${DealNumber}</a>"  
             template: "<a>${DealIssuer}</a>"

         }, {
             field: "Ticker",
             width: 150,
             title: "Ticker",
             filterable: {
                 operators: {
                     string: {
                         startswith: "Starts With",
                         contains: "Contains"
                     }
                 }
             }    
         }, {
             field: "DealExchange",
             width: 150,
             title: "Exchange",
             filterable: {
                 operators: {

                     string: {
                         startswith: "Starts With",
                         contains: "Contains"
                     }
                 }
             }
         }, {
             field: "DealType",
             width: 150,
             title: "Type",
             filterable: {
                 operators: {
                     string: {
                         startswith: "Starts With",
                         contains: "Contains"
                     }
                 }
             }

         }, {
             field: "DealValue",
             width: 150,
             title: "Value ($m)",
             filterable: {
                 operators: {
                     string: {
                         startswith: "Starts With",
                         contains: "Contains"
                     }
                 }
             },
             /*   template: '#= kendo.culture("en-US");kendo.toString(${DealValue/1000000},"p")#' */

             template: '#= kendo.toString(DealValue,"c2") #'

         }, {
             field: "DealStatus",
             width: 150,
             title: "Status",
             filterable: {
                 operators: {
                     string: {
                         startswith: "Starts With",
                         contains: "Contains"
                     }
                 }
             }

         }, {
             field: "DealPricingCompletionDate",
             width: 230,
             title: "DealPricingCompletionDate",
             format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",
             filterable: {
                 ui: "datetimepicker",
                 operators: {
                     date: {
                         gt: "After",
                         lt: "Before",
                         eq: "Equals"
                     },
                     messages: {
                         filter: "Apply",
                         clear: "Clear"
                     }
                 }

             }
         },   
         ],

         change: function () {
             var text = "";
             var grid = this;
             grid.select().each(function () {
                 var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this));
                 text += "DealNumber: " + dataItem.DealNumber + "\n" + "Issuer: " + dataItem.DealIssuer + "\n" + "Ticker: " + dataItem.Ticker + "\n" + "Type: " + dataItem.DealType + "\n" + "Value: " + dataItem.DealValue + "\n" +
                     "Status " + dataItem.DealStatus + "\n" + "DealPricingCompletionDate: " + kendo.toString(dataItem.DealPricingCompletionDate, "dd/MM/yyyy");
             });
             alert(text);
         },
         height: 700
     }).data("kendoGrid");
```

Comment: where is the `change` method being called?

Comment: It gets called automatically as soon as the user selects one of the row in the grid. thats why there is an attibute called    selectable: "row",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long delay its been cracked now.
All i had to do was use SetTimeOut Method by timeout as 0 meaning do not specify any time parameter.
So the fixed code is

```
    function onRowSelected(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.sender);
        var text = "";
        var grid = this;
        grid.select().each(function () {
            var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this));
            text += "DealNumber: " + dataItem.DealNumber + "\n" + "Issuer: " +
                dataItem.DealIssuer + "\n" + "Ticker: " + dataItem.Ticker + "\n" + "Type: " + dataItem.DealType + "\n" + "Value: " + dataItem.DealValue + "\n" +
                "Status " + dataItem.DealStatus + "\n" + "DealPricingCompletionDate: " + kendo.toString(dataItem.DealPricingCompletionDate, "dd/MM/yyyy");
        });
        setTimeout(function () { alert(text) },0);

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The change event is being triggered twice, and since the `alert()` is being bound to the change event, it will also pop up twice.

Take a look at the [change event documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-change). It is "Fired when the user selects a table row or cell in the grid."

Perhaps it is being fired twice, one for the row and one for the cell? Although I see you have `selectable: "row"` so it should only fire for the row.

Update your change event to `change: function (e) { console.log(e); }` and see what it outputs in your debug console. This will give you a hint as to what element it is being triggered on.

You can then try adding `e.preventDefault();` to your change event to stop any other event from being triggered.

Comment: Is there a way to stop this from occuring twice  as the change event gets triggered automatically as soon as i select a row

Comment: Hi @nullability i tried that it seems like it gets triggered via cell click and i see that its only fired once. i also tried the e.preventDefault() but still have to press ok button twice to make the popup disappear

Comment: Hi @nullability its been fixed now. Thank you for your time and effort. Really appreciate it. Keep up the good work